# validate multiple rows with multiple regex from two pandas df

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to validate, if zip code for many different countries which stored in a table are in a correct format, as an example:

| ZIP | COUNTRY_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1033 SC | NL |
| 60593 | DE |

To do that I have a separate DF with country code and regular expressions as a pattern for every zip code.

| REGEX | COUNTRY |
| --- | --- |
| \d{4}[ ]?[A-Z]{2} | NL |
| \d{5} | DE |

I'm trying to merge this to tables based on a coutry code and then create which indicates as True or False if the zip code based on regex is correct.

Here is my currecnt code:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(regex_df, zip_df,  left_on = 'CODE',   right_on= 'COUNTRY_CODE')
df_merged['zip_correct'] = df_mergedf.CODE_y.str.contains(df_merged.REGEX.str, regex= True, na=False)
```

Hovewer I'm etting only false results since pandas is cheking the regex pattern in every row. How could I limit it to check it row by row?

Expected output:

| ZIP | COUNTRY_CODE | ZIP_CORRECT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1033 SC | NL | TRUE |
| 60593 | DE | TRUE |
| 6059TT | DE | FALSE |

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you might have many countries. You can `apply` `re.match` with the matching country regex on each row:

```
import re

s = regex_df.set_index('COUNTRY')['REGEX']

df['ZIP_CORRECT'] = df.apply(lambda x: bool(re.match('%s$' % s[x['COUNTRY_CODE']], x['ZIP'])), axis=1)
```

output:

```
       ZIP COUNTRY_CODE  ZIP_CORRECT
0  1033 SC           NL         True
1    60593           DE         True
2   6059TT           DE        False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

zip_df = pd.DataFrame({"ZIP":["1033 SC", "60593"], "COUNTRY_CODE": ["NL","DE"]})
regex_df = pd.DataFrame({"REGEX":[r"\d{4}[ ]?[A-Z]{2}", "\d{5}"], "COUNTRY": ["NL","DE"]})

d = dict(regex_df[['COUNTRY', 'REGEX']].to_numpy())
zip_df['ZIP_CORRECT'] = zip_df.apply(lambda x: bool(re.fullmatch(d[x['COUNTRY_CODE']], x['ZIP'])), axis=1)
```

The `d` dictionary will look like `{'NL': '\\d{4}[ ]?[A-Z]{2}', 'DE': '\\d{5}'}`, and within the `.apply()`, each `ZIP` value from the `zip_df` dataframe is checked against the appropriate regex pattern from the dictionary as it is obtained form the `d` dictionary using the `zip_df` `COUNTRY_CODE` value as a key.

**Note** that [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) only returns *True* if the regex pattern *fully* matches the string, i.e. matches the entire string.

Test in Pandas (copy/pasted):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import re
>>> zip_df = pd.DataFrame({"ZIP":["1033 SC", "60593", "6059TT"], "COUNTRY_CODE": ["NL","DE","DE"]})
>>> regex_df = pd.DataFrame({"REGEX":[r"\d{4}[ ]?[A-Z]{2}", "\d{5}"], "COUNTRY": ["NL","DE"]})
>>> d = dict(regex_df[['COUNTRY', 'REGEX']].to_numpy())
>>> zip_df['ZIP_CORRECT'] = zip_df.apply(lambda x: bool(re.fullmatch(d[x['COUNTRY_CODE']], x['ZIP'])), axis=1)
>>> zip_df
       ZIP COUNTRY_CODE  ZIP_CORRECT
0  1033 SC           NL         True
1    60593           DE         True
2   6059TT           DE        False
>>>
```

Comment: nice, I forgot about `re.fullmatch` ;)

Comment: @mozway Yeah, it is convenient here. Something is happening to SO editing feature, I have to confirm every edit today :(

Comment: me too, and then it shows a blank post until I refresh, hope it will be fixed soon ;)

Comment: thanks a lot, but it is giving me different key errors....

Comment: @Volume069 See https://imgur.com/a/ihHCAAg, there are no errors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Q1 : why `.to_numpy())` and not `.values`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Q2 : why going through a dict? Would it not be simpler to `regex_df.set_index('COUNTRY')` then in the lambda get the regex via `regex_df['REGEX'][x['COUNTRY_CODE']]`

Comment: @hpchavaz Because it works. Why not?